# Why are not all TypeScript syntax or semantic errors shown in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, ts-node, typescript-eslint

I am writing a program in TypeScript within VScode. My project has these dependencies:

```js
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.20.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.20.0",
"eslint": "^8.14.0",
"ts-node": "^10.7.0",
"typescript": "^4.3.4",
[...]
```

I also added a `tsconfig.json` and `.eslintrc.json` to my project. Within VScode I can see errors (as expected) like the following:

[image: VScode with syntax error]

As you can see, errors like the one below are not marked, also not by `eslint`.

[image]

They **only** show up when I use [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) to try run the file.

```
$ node --require ts-node/register main.ts
...foo/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:820
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
    ../main.ts(179,42): error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

Comment: It shows errors from up to bottom. If you fix first error, then you will get the next.

Comment: I can't confirm this. If I remove the "first" error, the second one is still not marked. Also, it's not a syntax error, it shouldn't apply in this case.

Comment: can you share your eslint configuration files?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question in a few minutes. But is this related to `eslint`, because the command-line complains about a TS error, not eslint warning

Comment: I think I know what happened. `strictNullChecks` was turned to `false` in my `tsconfig.json`. It seems `ts-node` ignores this setting somehow and that's why it doesn't go through.